# Under what circumstances can you be convicted of indecent exposure for being naked in a California changing room?

Tags: california

Recent events have seen a person (with a history of sexual offending) charged for indecent exposure in the changing room of a nude spa in Los Angeles.

However, I am confused because surely a changing room necessarily involves the nude exposure of body parts not ordinarily exposed.  Under what circumstances can you be charged with indecent exposure in a setting where nudity is necessary in California?

Answer (score 3):

That would be when he [does so willfully and lewdly](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=314.&lawCode=PEN). Simple nudity is not illegal. See for instance [in re Dallas W.](https://law.justia.com/cases/california/court-of-appeal/4th/85/937.html), where the court found that sexual intent is necessary: "'something more than mere nudity' must be shown", citing [In re Smith](https://law.justia.com/cases/california/supreme-court/3d/7/362.html) (1972) 7 Cal. 3d 36. A propos this incident, the [reported partial erection](https://nypost.com/2021/09/02/charges-filed-against-sex-offender-in-wi-spa-casecharges-filed-against-sex-offender-in-notorious-wi-spa-incident/) is not irrelevant.